# jQuery Slides doesn't automatically slide after using next/prev

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow

I'm using the following jQuery plugin:

http://slidesjs.com/

I've set the `play` attribute to `30000` so that the slideshow will change to the next slide every 30 seconds.

This works fine, until you manually change the current slide by using the `next/prev` options.

If these are used, afterwards the slide never automatically changes without having to use the arrows to do so.

On the example on [slidejs.com](http://slidesjs.com/) this doesn't seem to be the case.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.slides').slides({
            next: 'right_arrow'
            , prev: 'left_arrow'
            , pagination: true
            , generatePagination: false
            , randomize: true
            , play: 30000
        });
    });
```

Why is this not working?

Comment: Please post your HTML-markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the pause option:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.slides').slides({
            next: 'right_arrow'
            , prev: 'left_arrow'
            , pagination: true
            , generatePagination: false
            , randomize: true
            , pause: 2500
            , play: 30000
        });
    });
```

Comment: Cheers @Kaz this has fixed my issue. Why does `pause` fix this?

Comment: pause (number)
Pause slideshow on click of next/prev or pagination. A positive number will set to true and be the time of pause in milliseconds. This option is very misleading